# VUE Js Cordova , navigator.device is undefined

Tags: android, cordova, vue.js, cordova-plugins, vue-cli-3

I am trying to implement audio recording using cordova-plugin-media-capture in VueJs Cli 3, Mean While I am facing navigator.device is undefined .Other features like navigator.vibration and navigator.camera are working fine .Tried with every workarounds in different forums still no luck , your valuable inputs are welcome

Have included cordova.js in index.html and installed the device plugin , still no use.

Main.ts

```
Vue.config.productionTip = false
const init = () => {
new Vue({
 router,
 store,
 vuetify,
 render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
}

declare let navigator : any;
declare let device : any;
document.addEventListener("deviceready", () => {
 init();
 console.log(navigator.device);
 console.log("Ready, Render the App");
});


// If we are not in Cordova, manually trigger the deviceready event
const isCordovaApp = false;
if (!isCordovaApp){
 document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("deviceready", {}));
}
```

Cordova Config.xml

```
 <content src="index.html" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="^2.0.3" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">
```

Comment: Just use device object directly.. Ex: `console.log(device)`

Comment: device is working  ...The actual problem is to implement cordova-plugin-media-capture , in that case navigator.device is undefined is  the exact problem.

Comment: you config.XML doesn't show the installed plugin `cordova-plugin-media-capture`. Did you install it?